# Stackoverflow exception on finite set

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code in a method. I have checked that data only returns 8 rows from the table and inner Foreach loop runs only 8 times. But I am getting Stackoverflow error after 8th element is added to the list.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM Courses";
var data = base.Select(query);

List<Course> list = new List<Course>();

foreach (DataTable table in data.Tables)
{
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("test1");
        var c = new Course();
        //c.Id = (int)row[0];
        //c.Name = row[1].ToString();
        //c.CrHrs = (float)row[2];
        list.Add(c);
    }
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Test");
}

return list;
```

[image]

Comment: The exception is thrown somewhere else. Show the complete stacktrace

Comment: We have no idea what the context is here. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Updated, please check now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `this.Name` as the return in the property which is incorrect...as the `Name` property is then recursively accessing itself in the "get" accessor.

You need to use the member variable.....probably `this.name` ?

Comment: What a catch *facepalm* I couldn't see that. thanks